# Why do small objects have to preverse colimits from directed sets, rather than colimits from semilattices?

Tags: category-theory, order-theory, cardinals, locally-presentable-categories

Let $\kappa$ be a regular cardinal. Let $\mathcal C$ be a category. Let $A : \mathcal C$ be an object of $\mathcal C$. As best I can tell, we say that $A$ is a [small object](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/small+object) of $\mathcal C$ if, for all $\kappa$-directed preorders $\mathcal J$ and diagrams $D : \mathcal J \to \mathcal C$ such that $D$ has a colimit in $\mathcal C$, we have an isomorphism between $\mathrm{colim}_X\ \mathrm{Hom}_\mathcal{C}(A, D(X))$ and $\mathrm{Hom}_\mathcal{C}(A, \mathrm{colim}_X D(X))$. (It perhaps makes sense to demand that $\mathcal C$ has all such limits, I can't tell from the nlab page whether that's standard.)

Now, define a $\kappa$-semilattice to be a preorder equipped with *least* upper bounds for any $\kappa$-indexed set of objects. (Contrast with the definition of a $\kappa$-directed preorder, which is equipped with mere upper bounds for any $\kappa$-indexed set of objects.)

Question: Why does the definition of a small object quantify across $\kappa$-directed preorders, instead of $\kappa$-semilattices? Is it just because $\kappa$-directions are a bit more general? Is it because it makes some of the small-$\kappa$ edge-cases work out in some desired fashion? Is it a mere convenience?

In particular, my intuitions say that if we ignore some of the small-$\kappa$ edge-cases, then the two definitions should work out to basically the same thing, but I'm not sure if I'm failing to visualize a way in which something goes terribly wrong if you use the semilattice version and $\kappa$ is particularly large.

(Note that by "small-$\kappa$" I mean 0, 1, and 2, which we may or may not consider regular cardinals depending on our choice of definition.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $J$ is a directed preorder, let $\bar J$ be the free cocompletion of $J$ under finite joins. There is a canonical functor $J\to \bar J$ which is cofinal, since a cocone under a diagram $F:\bar J\to \mathcal C$ is canonically determined by its restriction to $J$. Meanwhile every functor $J\to \mathcal C$ extends canonically to $\bar J$, assuming $\mathcal C$ has finite coproducts. Thus, assuming $\mathcal C$ has finite coproducts, then it has directed colimits if and only if it has colimits of diagrams indexed by sup-semilattices, and we have also the analogous claim for functors out of $\mathcal C$ preserving such colimits. Thus in a $\mathcal C$ with finite coproducts, an object is $\aleph_0$-small if and only if its homs out commute with colimits indexed by sup-semilattices. The generalizations to uncountable cardinals hold as well.

However, it is not unusual that we want to consider directed colimits in a category $\mathcal C$ *lacking* finite coproducts-this is more or less the subject of finitely accessible categories. In this case it is not clear that we can extend a $J$-indexed diagram to $\bar J$ as we needed above. That's no problem for $\kappa=\aleph_0$-in fact, a category has and a functor preserved directed colimits if and only if it preserves colimits of chains, that is, functors indexed by ordinals. As totally ordered sets, chains certainly have finite coproducts. This result is 1.7 in Adamek and Rosicky's book on locally presentable categories.

However, it is *not* the case that general $\kappa$-directed colimits can be constructed from colimits of $\kappa$-filtered chains (which would be the kind of chains forming $\kappa$-semilattices in your sense.) So it seems conceivable that there may exist, say, a category (necessarily lacking $\kappa$-small coproducts) in which there is some object homs out of which commute with colimits over $\aleph_1$-semilattices but not over all $\aleph_1$-directed preorders. It is easy to imagine that whether such a category and object exist is an open question, but I don't know for sure. I also agree with Mark that the canonical diagram shouldn't be a $\kappa$-semilattice in general in an accessible category, although it is in a locally presentable category and in the main examples of non-presentable accessible categories that come to mind.

So in summary, nothing goes wrong for $\aleph_0$-small objects, but something might go wrong for larger $\kappa$; it seems at best not obvious whether this is the case. That, together with the fact that focusing on $\kappa$-semilattices doesn't give any immediate simplification to the theory, seems sufficient to justify sticking with $\kappa$-directed sets in general.

By the way, a $\kappa$-directed preorder should have upper bounds for subset of cardinality *less* than $\kappa$, so you probably want to define a $\kappa$-sup-semilattice analogously. For instance an $\aleph_0$-sup-semilattice is then just a sup-semilattice.

Answer (score 0):

Let's first see why we would call such objects small.

Concrete example: let $\kappa = \omega$ (the countable cardinal) and work in the category $\mathbf{Set}$ of sets. Then a set $A$ is $\omega$-presentable ("$\omega$-compact" on the page you linked) precisely when $|A| < \omega$, i.e. precisely when $A$ is finite.

To see this, note that an isomorphism $\operatorname{colim}_X \operatorname{Hom}(A, D(X)) \cong \operatorname{Hom}(A, \operatorname{colim}_X D(X))$, for an $\omega$-directed diagram $D$, means precisely that any arrow $A \to \operatorname{colim}_X D(X)$ will factor through the diagram in an essentially unique way. That is, it factors as $A \xrightarrow{f_Y} D(Y) \to \operatorname{colim}_X D(X)$ where $Y$ is some object in our $\omega$-directed preorder. The "essentially unique" requirement means that if $f$ factors through both $f_Y: A \to D(Y)$ and $f_{Y'}: A \to D(Y')$, then there is $Y, Y' \leq Z$ in the preorder such that $D(Y \leq Z) f_Y = D(Y' \leq Z) f_{Y'}$.

Now suppose $A$ is finite and let $f: A \to \operatorname{colim}_X D(X)$ be a function. We have to show that it factors through the diagram. Since $A$ is finite, we can write $A = \{a_1, \ldots, a_n\}$. For each $1 \leq i \leq n$ there is $X_i$ such that $f(a_i) \in D(X_i)$. This is because a colimit in $\mathbf{Set}$ is just (a quotient of) a union. Since the diagram is $\omega$-directed, there must be some $Y$ that is the upper bound of $\{X_1, \ldots, X_n\}$. Hence $f$ factors through $D(Y)$.

Conversely, suppose $A$ is $\omega$-presentable. Let $\mathcal{P}_\text{fin}(A)$ be the set of finite subsets of $A$. This becomes an $\omega$-directed diagram when we consider the inclusions between those subsets. Since clearly $A = \operatorname{colim} \mathcal{P}_\text{fin}(A)$, we must have that the identity $Id_A$ factor through the diagram. But then it factor through a finite set, so $A$ must be finite.

---

So let's look at the proof strategy. In the forward direction ($A$ finite implies $A$ $\omega$-presentable) we had an arrow $f$ into some $\omega$-directed colimit. We were able to piece together the image of $A$ under $f$ already in the diagram itself, and that is precisely what we want. We want to say that $A$ contains so little information, that if we send that information into a colimit (think: "a union"), then all bits of information can already be pieced together inside the diagram of that colimit. This is the intuition why we do not require least upper bounds in the diagram.

---

These kinds of objects play a central role in [locally presentable categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/locally+presentable+category) and the more general [accessible categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/accessible+category) (where indeed the existence of $\kappa$-directed colimits is assumed for some big enough $\kappa$). One important property there is that every object can be built as a $\kappa$-directed colimit of $\kappa$-presentable objects (much like we did with $A = \operatorname{colim} \mathcal{P}_\text{fin}(A)$ before). In general these diagrams will not be $\kappa$-semilattices.

Comment: Thanks! I found this comment helpful, but I don't think it quite answers my question. The first part sounds to me like it's arguing for "it's a convenience" (ie, "the directed version most closely matches the style of the proofs we want"), whereas the last part ("in general these diagrams will not be $\kappa$-semilattices") sounds like it's arguing for "something goes wrong if you use semilattices in general". Do you know whether the definition is the same (modulo edge cases) but less convenient in the semilattice case? If not, can you point more precisely to what goes wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Also, I don't quite follow the argument that we have an isomorphism if every Hom(A, colim D) factors through Hom(A, D(X)) for some X. Perhaps I'm just being daft, but suppose we have an (a : colim_X Hom(A, D(X))), and we pull an (a' : Hom(A, D(X'))) out of the disjoint union, and turn it into a (b : Hom(A, colim D)) in the natural way. Then we run our factorizer to get an (a'' : Hom(A, D(X'')). How do we know that a' ~ a'' under the quotient? I think that's false in general, so we must be using some property of directed diagrams, but it's not clear to me which one. (Or is this omega-specific?)

Comment: @Nate You're right, more is needed. The "every map factors through" condition says that colim Hom(A,D(X)) to Hom(A,colim D(X)) is surjective. To say it's injective, you also need to assert that if f: A to colim D(X) factors through f',f'':A to D(X'),D(X''), then f' and f'' are equalized when mapped to D(X''') for some X''' an upper bound of X' and X''. This condition is redundant if, as is common, all the maps in the values of D, as well as the legs of the colimiting cocone, are mono.

Comment: @KevinCarlson thanks! Do you know off the top of your head how to repair the argument in the OP for general D (ie, when not everything is mono)? Alternatively, why don't we say $A$ is $\kappa$-small whenever colim Hom(A, D(X)) to Hom(A, colim D(X)) is surjective?

Comment: For instance, IIUC, if we allow finite regular cardinals, the empty set is not 2-small if we require isomorphism (let J be the diagram w/ only 2 objs), but it is 2-small if we require only surjection. This is an edge case, obv, but if we want to make arguments like the one in the OP w/out worrying too much about injectivity, and if it degrades nicer in the edge cases (∅ obviously "should" be 2-small), then I start to suspect that it's a more natural def'n. (Ofc, I don't know how much we rely on the injectivity of the map between homs in practice.)

Comment: @Nate I did indeed forget to mention that the factorisation must be essentially unique, which is precisely what Kevin spelled out. I added that to my post. I mostly wanted to indicate why this is the right definition to work with. Kevin's answer makes a good point about two different cases when we could consider $\kappa$-semilattices. I also do not know any concrete counterexamples for the more general case.

Comment: Thanks @KevinCarlson also for pointing this out.

Comment: @Nate Finally I should mention that in all this we do not really consider finite $\kappa$. For $\kappa = 2$  we would just be looking at any colimit indexed by any non-empty poset (or preorder), because any subset of size $\leq 1$ trivially has an upper bound. For $2 < k < \omega$ the notions of $k$-directed and $\omega$-directed are equivalent. For a finite set $\{a_1, \ldots, a_n\}$ in some 3-directed poset we can find an upper bound $b_1$ of $a_1$ and $a_2$, then an upper bound $b_2$ of $a_3$ and $b_1$, and continue this to obtain an upper bound of $\{a_1, \ldots, a_n\}$.

Comment: @Nate I know no examples of the plain surjectivity condition holding for arbitrary directed colimits, unless the bijectivity condition holds. It's good to have in mind that an $\aleph_0$-small object in the typical categories of abstract algebra is precisely a finitely presentable (group, ring, etc.) We can say that an object in such a category is finitely *generated* if and only if it satisfies the surjectivity condition for all filtered colimits of monomorphisms, but then again the injectivity is automatic, so might as well require bijectivity.

Comment: A 2-small object, in the standard definition, is sometimes called "tiny", or "small-projective", and this is a useful notion-for instance a presheaf category is precisely a cocomplete category with a strong generator consisting of tiny objects. So I don't know that I agree than $\emptyset$ "should" be 2-small. In any case, it's true that one usually exclusively considers small objects relative to an infinite regular cardinal.

Comment: Thanks! @Kevin, I don't quite understand what you mean by "then again the injectivity is automatic" -- is there something I'm missing about how satisfying the surjectivity condition for all filtered colimits of monomorphisms implies satisfying the injectivity condition for all filtered colimits in full generality?

Comment: Also, I thought that the tiny objects were the 0-small objects, not the 2-small objects (b/c their homs preserve all small colimits, including the empty diagram, and the empty diagram is not 2-filtered). Am I wrong?

Comment: @Nate You're right, I take that back about 2-small. Turns out I know no reason to consider 2-smallness in either the bijectivity or surjectivity forms. No, I don't claim the injectivity is automatic in any case for general directed diagrams, just that an object is "surjectivity-$\kappa$ small with respect to directed diagrams of monomorphisms" if and only if it's "$\kappa$-small with respect to directed diagrams of monomorphisms," which is sometimes called being $\kappa$-generated.